# Getting an "Invalid object name" error in ADS after creating a new table

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-studio

I'm working on a new Jupyter Notebook, using SQL as the Kernel, to create a new table, populate it with a couple records, etc., then drop the table. I've written the CREATE TABLE DDL, then ran it. However, when I ran it in ADS it gave me an error on the table name ("Invalid object name ") and each column in the new table ("Invalid column name "). But it created the table, nonetheless. Huh? What's going on?

I've looked for similar questions posted here on SO, but none of the match my situation. For example, one of them the user had created the table as one name, but then tried to do a SELECT against a different table name, that was slightly different from the one they created. That's not the case for me. Here's the SQL DDL for creating the table:

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Bozo]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Bozo]
GO
-- Create the table in the specified schema
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bozo]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- Primary Key column
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    -- Specify more columns here
    Bool1 BIT DEFAULT 1,
    Bool2 BIT DEFAULT 1,
    BoolValue AS Bool1 & Bool2
);
GO
```

And here's my SQL INSERT statements:

```sql
NSERT INTO Bozo (FirstName, LastName)
VALUES ('George', 'Washington');
INSERT INTO Bozo (FirstName, LastName, Bool2)
VALUES ('John', 'Adams', 0);
```

Comment: I would suggest that you aren't connected to the same database you created the table in. Perhaps, for example, you created the table in `master` in error.

Comment: (For consistency, I'd also make sure you _always_ use the schema prefix. Why use `dbo.` in one script but not the other?)

Comment: I used the template script that Azure Data Studio provides for creating a new table. 10 minutes after posting my question I realized what the issue was. That template defined column Id as `INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY`. I thought it had also used `IDENTITY`, but I was wrong. Changing that fixed the problem.

Comment: That wouldn't generate the error you got though, @Rod . Omitting the column `ID` from the `INSERT` statement would generate the error `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table '{Database}.dbo.Bozo'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.` *not* an Invalid Object Name error. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e6d09e6e872b01dca736a907e8e46172)

Answer (score -1):

I discovered that the SQL Script that Azure Data Studio uses to create a new table does not define the Id column as an IDENTITY column. Changing that fixed the issue, so now it is:

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Bozo]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Bozo]
GO
-- Create the table in the specified schema
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bozo]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- Primary Key column
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    -- Specify more columns here
    Bool1 BIT DEFAULT 1,
    Bool2 BIT DEFAULT 1,
    BoolValue AS Bool1 & Bool2
);
GO
```